# auto js injected in js files [ default/base.js ] using Moblink 3G

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-injection, 3g

I am using moblink 3G internet and a script like

```
 <script type = 'text/javascript' id ='1qa2ws' charset='utf-8' src='http://10.227.18.38:8080/www/default/base.js'></script>
```

is added at the end of all the javascript files. Can anybody please help?
I think this is ISP issue because I have scanned the full PC and even refreshed my operating system.

Looking forward to hear from you
Thanks

Comment: Well, we're not IT help support. Please, contact your ISP regarding this.

Comment: i have contacted ISP but still not solved

Comment: Try googling ":8080/www/default/base.js" between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is only http:// and https:// problem. When I tried http://itsolpak.blogspot.com google ads and other java were not working but https://itsolpak.blogspot.com is problem less and active javascripts.